# Powershell: How to fetch word after special character

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grep the word after the character(=), but can't able to grep it.
**command:**\

```
powermt display dev=all | Select-String 'Logical device ID'\
```

**current output**:

```
Logical device ID=abcd
Logical device ID=efgh
```

**expected output**:

```
abcd
efgh
```

Tried with `Select-Object` and `Select-Object -Property` its not working.

Comment: What's the output of `powermt display dev=all` ?

Comment: You can do `powermt display dev=all | Select-String 'Logical device ID=(.*)' |% {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}`

Comment: Output was added in this link. https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/powermt-command-examples/

Comment: Add to your question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`Select-String "Logical device ID=(.+)").Matches.Groups[1].Value`